# Display half of the image in Front and half in back

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lv6kyL8t/15/ .  On mouseover image, i am rotating the image 360 degree.

When image is rotating in fiddle , you can see 2 sides - both **front** and **back** side of **mug** showing full image of **car.** But what i need is I want to display **first half** of the car in Front side & **second half** of the car in back side.

so that one car will cover the entire mug

```css
#simple1 {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 62px;
  height: 91px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 400px;
  margin: 55px;
  left: 10px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}

.container:hover #card {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 360deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <img id="simple1" class="back" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/q60IC.jpg' alt='Title of image'></img>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just tossing ideas: maybe GIF or WebGL would be (easier) alternatives? Apart from that, you could (probably) use JavaScript to change the image `src` once you reach 180 degree.

Comment: @domdom thanks, but once customer upload any format of image in site , we are converting that to PNG format..... GIF will not work in our case i guess.....

Comment: @domdom sorry, the 2nd suggestion also will not work in our case  as we have only one image..... as these images will upload by customer . we cant manually add image `src` each time......

Comment: I think theoretically you would be able to translate the image of the car so that from `0-90deg` and `270-360deg` the front half would be shown on top of the mug (and the back half would fall outside the container). And than from `90-270deg` the backside would show (and the front half would fall outside the container). **THE PROBLEM IS** that in any case you would need a separate image of the mug and the car. Since you have only one image with the mug and the full car on it, there is no way to hide half of the car without also hiding that same half of the mug.

Comment: BTW, [images don't have closing tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp). They are self-closing; either `<img ...>` or `<img ... />` (the second one being in compliance with XHTML).

Comment: @myfunkyside thanks, are you telling i need to use 2 images like here : https://jsfiddle.net/reb50woL/2/ ? if i am wrong, please clarify me or is i need 2 images with 1st image contains first half of the car and 2nd image contains next half of the car to achieve this ?.....

Comment: Maybe a little background/context would help. Is this supposed to be service where users can upload an image (for example of a car) that will then be shown on a mug? If so, I totally agree with @myfunkyside - you need to separate those. Or, as I said in my first comment, go with WebGL. I would go with WebGL.

Comment: @domdom your assumption is right, here users going to upload single image and we need to place half of that image in front side of mug and another half of image in backside of mug.....

Comment: Yep. I would then put in the effort to model a mug and setup WebGL once. This has the benefit that you can easily overlay user's images onto the mug, change mug color, let the mug be shiny, let the user rotate (in all directions) and zoom in/out on the mug freely, add in a background scene (office desk?) and so many more. Heck, you could even add steaming coffee. Given that a mug is a relatively simple geometry and there are probably free models available, this seems very feasible. Also, three.js and so on are your friends.

Comment: Yes, you would need two images, but not like you suggested. Better would be to have the 1st image of the empty mug, and then the 2nd image of only the car (or whatever object). You would then overlay the image of the mug with the image of the car (car has transparent background). And then use `translateX` to translate the image of the car `50%` to either the right or the left. **But I agree with @domdom**, I'm not familiar with using WebGL but it seems like a far superior option (assuming browser support is sufficient).

Comment: Added benefit of using either the two separate images or the WebGL, is that you can always use the same image for the mug, you wouldn't have to change that. Only the image of the object that is shown on the mug changes, which is probably the image you would get from your customers anyway. So there is less work for you, you only have to ask your customers to upload the images as PNG with transparent background (or do that yourself like you are doing now, but the mug image can remain untouched).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split two images into separate view and use something like this

```css
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.flip-container.vertical:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-container.horizontal:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {    
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.flip-container.vertical .flipper {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100px;    
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 1;
    background: #3498db;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}

.back {    
    background: #2ecc71;
}

.flip-container.horizontal .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container.vertical .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container horizontal">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            FRONT
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            BACK
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container vertical">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            FRONT
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            BACK
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, right now i have single image with `car overlay on mug` , is there is any option to get solution with single image ?

Comment: You cannot split the image. You can try using background image and background position but when its dynamic its not optimal solution.

Comment: so using `background image and background position` i can split the both `mug and car` and  i can display `first half` of the car in `front` of the mug and `second half` of the car in `backside` of mug ?

Comment: Yes. You need to repeat the image. That might work. This is thought. Try out.

Comment: is there any online link so that  i can follow because whatever i tried with `background image and background position` also i can able to cut the half of the complete image [ car and mug ] , but i cant able to cut only half of car and display full mug......

Comment: also the position of car is not static, means some users may place the car on top of the mug and some may place at bottom and some users may place the image in middle, in all cases `first half of the car` should be in `front of the mug` & `second half of the car` should display in `back of the mug`.....

Comment: OP, if you want to have a *single image* for both, the mug as well as the car, it is *impossible* to change the position of the car on the mug. Because an image is an image is an image. You *need* them separate; at least server-side so you can compose the final image from them. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, and Shahil, your Snippet doesn't work on FF/Debian. Probably just missing `-moz` prefix though.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the discussion from the comment section:
**What you are trying to do is not possible with the assets you currently have.**

I can see three possible approaches that will give you the functionality you want.
The key, however, is to separate the (image of the) mug from the user image (car).

1. **CSS rotation with separate images**
   Use one image for the mug itself and then overlay the user's image on top of it. Then pretty much do what you're doing now. It will probably be tricky to get them positioned and rotated correctly so that the illusion holds. Plus, the visualization of the mug will be quite limited. Frankly, I recommend against this.
2. **Compose images**
   You could use image libraries (JavaScript or PHP) or some math and image manipulation algorithms in order to morph the user's image onto some prepared images of a blank mug from different angles (front, back, left, right). You can then show these composed images to the user. This will limit the possible angles but should give decent results. If you do the composing server-side, browser support would be a no-brainer. I would go with this only if the WebGL solution is not feasible for whatever reason.
3. **WebGL**
   My recommended method. Model a mug (or all of the possible cups) once. Add in a couple of extra faces around the mug. Then render the mug with WebGL and display the user's image on the extra faces in order to overlay them onto the mug. This requires some reading into WebGL, but thanks to libraries like three.js, this might turn out easier than the second approach. The only downside might be the fact that even a high poly mug will never look absolutely real. The upside is that this is extremely flexible: you could allow users to rotate the mug 360 degrees on all axis, zoom in and out; you could add in a background scene (maybe an office desk) or even fill the mug with steaming coffee. Adding some specular maps and a proper light source, your mug will be nice and shiny.